# Javascript Random Alphanumeric Generator, Specific Format

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a random alphanumeric generator using javascript that will randomly generate a vehicle registration number, so the string MUST be in a specific format: three capital letters, three numbers, two capital letters.  First three letters and numbers can be totally random i.e. ABC123, or GDS342.  The last two letters are abbreviations for specific provinces/states i.e. MP, ZN, GP etc. An example: GDS342GP.
When a button is clicked on the webpage, the registration number should then be displayed in a textarea.

Any advise on how to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information. Let's start with some snippets that you've worked on regarding the matter! (if you need help with this, read up on how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode()` will give you a capital letter if you enter numbers from 65 to 90. So if you use this function 3 times with 3 random numbers between (and including) 65-90 you can generate three random capital letters:

```js
const getRandomLetters = function(count) {
  let acc = ''; // the resulting string (to return once results appended)
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) { // generate amount
    const randomCharCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * (91 - 65)) + 65;
    acc += String.fromCharCode(randomCharCode);
  }
  return acc;
}

const characters = getRandomLetters(3);
console.log(characters);
```

To generate the three random numbers you can do this much in the same way. To do this you can use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)` to generate a random integer from 0 to 9. There are easier ways to do this, but this method will allow you to get numbers such as `000` or `050` which aren't in the hundreds but still considered three numbers:

```js
const getRandomNumbers = function(count) {
  let acc = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    acc += ~~(Math.random() * 10); // Note: ~~ is the same as Math.floor (just a little faster)
  }
  return acc;
}

const numbers = getRandomNumbers(3);
console.log(numbers);
```

Since you haven't specified how states are picked, I'll provide you with a way which picks them randomly.

You can store all your states in an array:

`const states = ['MP', 'ZN', 'GP'];`

And then pick a random number between (and including) zero to the length of your states array minus 1 to get a random index from this array. This will then allow you to access a random state by using this number as an index:

```js
const states = ['MP', 'ZN', 'GP'];
const randomIndex = ~~(Math.random() * states.length); // random int from: [0, 3) -> gives ints: 0, 1, 2

const state = states[randomIndex];
console.log(state);
```

Now you can combine all of these ideas to generate your random string. You can also add an `onclick` method to your `<button>` element which will call a function when pressed. Also, you can also add an `id` to your `<textarea>` so that your javascript access it and change its `value` to be the generated string:

```js
const getRandomLetters = function(count) {
  let acc = ''; // the resulting string (to return once results appended)
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) { // generate amount
    let randomCharCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * (91 - 65)) + 65;
    acc += String.fromCharCode(randomCharCode);
  }
  return acc;
}




const getRandomNumbers = function(count) {
  let acc = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    acc += ~~(Math.random() * 10); // Note: ~~ is the same as Math.floor (just a little faster)
  }
  return acc;
}

const generatePlate = function() {
  const states = ['MP', 'ZN', 'GP'];
  const randomIndex = ~~(Math.random() * states.length); // random int from: [0, 3) -> gives ints: 0, 1, 2
  
  const characters = getRandomLetters(3);
  const numbers = getRandomNumbers(3);
  const state = states[randomIndex];
  
  const resultPlate = characters + numbers  + state;
  document.getElementById('output').value = resultPlate;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generatePlate()">Generate</button>
<br />
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```